# Table selection

Tags: c#, linq

The user can select any comb of cells from the table. How can I generate a LINQ request if I don’t know in advance how many cells the user will select?

```
db.P.Where(p => p.Date == "01.01.2000");
db.P.Where(p => p.FirstName == "Vitaly");
```

For example, he will select a **Date** and the **First Name** it will look like this:
[image]

But if you choose a different combination or more cells?

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with C. Maybe excel.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to approach this, but I think a straightforward one would be a filter type. Since you allow for multiple possible values per property, the filter should contain collections of each row property that can be filtered and provide a match function to test a row.

For example:

```
class Row
{
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}

class Filter
{
    public ICollection<string> Dates { get; } = new HashSet<string>();
    public ICollection<string> FirstNames { get; } = new HashSet<string>();

    public bool Matches(Row row) =>
        row != null
        && EmptyOrContains(Dates, row.Date)
        && EmptyOrContains(FirstNames, row.FirstName);

    private static bool EmptyOrContains<T>(ICollection<T> filter, T value) =>
        !filter.Any() || filter.Contains(value);
}
```

From here you would be able to use `rows.Where(i => filter.Matches(i))` to select all rows that match the filter set.

Answer (score 0):

you already know how to make predicate expressions (lambda expressions)

```
p => p.FirstName == "Vitaly"
```

let's have a look at the type of that expression...

`Func<T,bool>` where `T` is the type of your entity

but the very same lambda expression can also be an expression tree of the following type

```
Expression<Func<T,bool>>
```

if you iterate over your selected cells, you can create those expressions for each cell... the question now is ... what to do with them...

you can chain those...

```
db.P.Where(lambda1).Where(lambda2)
```

but what you want is more likely a combination ... one expression tree that ANDs all those other expression trees

have a look over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60937819/706119) on how to do that...